# Accessible variables at the root of a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've declared a number of variables at the start of my script, as I'm using them in a number of different methods ("Functions" in python?). When I try to access them, I can't seem to get their value = or set them to another value for that matter. For example:

```
baseFile = open('C:/Users/<redacted>/Documents/python dev/ATM/Data.ICSF', 'a+')
secFile = open('C:/Users/<redacted>/Documents/python dev/ATM/security.ICSF', 'a+')

def usrInput(raw_input):
    if raw_input == "99999":
        self.close(True)
    else:
        identity = raw_input

def splitValues(source, string):
    if source == "ident":
        usrTitle = string.split('>')[1]
        usrFN = string.split('>')[2]
        usrLN = string.split('>')[3]
        x = string.split('>')[4]
        usrBal = Decimal(x)
        usrBalDisplay = str(locale.currency(usrBal))
    elif source == "sec":
        usrPIN = string.split('>')[1]
        pinAttempts = string.split('>')[2]

def openAccount(identity):
    #read all the file first. it's f***ing heavy but it'll do here.
    plString = baseFile.read()
    xList = plString.split('|')
    parm = str(identity)
    for i in xList:
        substr = i[0:4]
        if parm == substr:
            print "success"
            usrString = str(i)
        else:
            lNumFunds = lNumFunds + 1      
    splitValues("ident", usrString)
```

When I place `baseFile` and `secFile` in the `openAccount` method, I can access the respective files as normal. However, when I place them at the root of the script, as in the example above, I can no longer access the file - although I can still "see" the variable.

Is there a reason to this? For reference, I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: That's because baseFile and secFile are global variables. In order to modify them, you have to re-declare them inside the function as global baseFile.

Comment: @blackmamba So I can definitely modify them? Does this affect the original variable? I want to pass these variables between functions with their updated values.

Comment: @blackmamba that's not true. If you want to have a local variable to modify, you'd need to do that, but *of course* python allows you to modify state of the surrounding scope.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I am not sure what you mean by "python allows you to modify state of the surrounding scope".

Comment: @Wolfish: Yes it does affect the original variable. Whenever you want to modify a global variable inside a function you have to re-declare it as global varname. But in case you are only reading them you can access it w/o redeclaring it. So you can get their updates values across functions. This link will give you better understanding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: @blackmamba So, my understanding is that I can use the `global` attribute, and pass updated values between functions, yes?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

> methods ("Functions" in python?)

"function" when they "stand free"; "methods" when they are members of a class. So, functions in your case.

What you describe does definitely work in python. Hence, my diagnosis is that you already `read` something from  the file elsewhere before you call `openAccount`, so that the read pointer is not at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Nope, I already thought of that. You can view the entire script here: http://pastebin.com/LSdYeR1G Note that the first function called is `login()`, which calls `openAccount()`.

Comment: However, is it possible that the problem lies with where I have put the first function call?

Comment: you're calling `openAccount` as many times as it takes to get a valid login; however, after the first attempt, the whole file has been read, so the read pointer is at the end of the file and you can't read it again!

Comment: I'm confused, I wrote the search function inside `openAccount()`, so I should only be calling it once?

Comment: but you call `openAccount()` multiple times, which contains the `read()`, right? After the first `read`, there will be nothing of the file left to read!

Comment: No, I only call it once - look at the `login()` function. If the login ID isn't recognised, it restarts the script, hence returning the `read()` pointer to 0, no?